# My Thread Function Runs with doubled arguments

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm making thread on foreach loop.

I give array value and count for the threads, and want to see the list.

But my thread[] is running with same count argument, randomly.

Also, T[0] doesn't get terminated normally. I guess this is with argu overlapping problem too..

This makes the result panel to be placed on other panels.

```
Thread[] T = new Thread[VA.Count];
int count = 0;
ThreadEnd = new CountdownEvent(VA.Count);

foreach (var item in VA)
{
    T[count] = new Thread(delegate () { SetResultBox(count, item); });
    T[count].Start();
    count++;
}
ThreadEnd.Wait();



private void SetResultBox(int RunCount, JToken item)
{
    VideoJson videoinfo = new VideoJson();
    videoinfo.title = item["snippet"]["title"].ToString();
    videoinfo.description = item["snippet"]["description"].ToString();
    videoinfo.ThumbnailURL = item["snippet"]["url"].ToString();

    VideoArray.Add(videoinfo);
    SearchResultControl SRC = new SearchResultControl(videoinfo);
    SRC.Location = new Point(0, RunCount * 110);
    ResultControlList.Add(SRC);
    ThreadEnd.Signal();
}
```

I want to know why SetResultBox function's argument is getting overlapped.

Important thing is that I hope there are no Join method.

If VA array gets bigger, this function works too slow with Join Func..

Comment: It very much sounds/looks like you're manipulating *UI* elements from multiple threads. In most UI frameworks (WinForms, WPF) that's a big *no*. UI work is done on one thread (the UI thread)

Comment: thanks, but there isn't any cross-thread errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implicitly capturing the context of `count` thus making the thread to use the value of `count` which is present at the time thread actually starts doing the job. I guess the `foreach` loop manages to iterate faster than the `Thread` actually starts. Declare a local variable which would make you a copy of the value as it is at the moment and it should run fine:

```
foreach (var item in VA)
{
    var currentCount = count;
    T[count] = new Thread(delegate () { SetResultBox(currentCount, item); });
    T[count].Start();
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very common problem, You need to create a dedicated variable for count to pass into the delegate / lambda

```
foreach (var item in VA)
{
    var count1 = count;
    T[count] = new Thread(delegate () { SetResultBox(count1, item); });
    T[count].Start();
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working really well <3
Can you tell me why I shoud make loacl variable for count?